# Ошибка в сборке gulp sass

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

Помогите выяснить в чем причина ошибки. Буду признателен за помощь.

```
igor@Usus:/media/Data/GitHub/gulp/my_first_proj$ gulp sass
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /media/Data/GitHub/gulp/my_first_proj/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node: failed to map segment from shared object
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at module.exports (/media/Data/GitHub/gulp/my_first_proj/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/Data/GitHub/gulp/my_first_proj/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
```

вот мой gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require ('gulp');
var sass = require ('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass') // Берем все sass файлы из папки sass и дочерних, если таковые будут
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

После долгих мытарств по сети, было принято решение переустановить ОС, собственно эти действия и избавили от ошибки.